# Multi-Table select

Tags: .net, linq, list, object, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to write a `Linq` statement that allows me to return a distinct list of

*`obj1 objects that contain obj2.sID == ASpecified# or obj3.sID == ASpecified#`*.

I tried to included an example of my entity diagram in hopes that my question would make more sense, but alas I do not have enough reputations. So I guess I will just need to do it in code. Below are my objects.

```
public class obj1
{
    public int obj1_id { get; set; }
    public String obj1Prop1 { get; set; }
    public String obj1Prop2 { get; set; }
    public List<obj2> obj2List { get; set; }
    public List<obj3> obj3List { get; set; }
}
public class obj2
{
    public int obj2_id { get; set; }
    public String obj2Prop1 { get; set; }
    public String obj2Prop2 { get; set; }
    public Int32 sID { get; set; }
}
public class obj3
{
    public int obj3_id { get; set; }
    public String obj3Prop1 { get; set; }
    public String obj3Prop2 { get; set; }
    public Int32 sID { get; set; }
}
```

I am fairly proficient with simple linq statements but am a little out of my league with this one. I am thinking that I will need to *join `obj3` and `obj2`* by the *sID* but am unsure.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join is not needed.
Try following code snippet

```
var o1 = new List<obj1>(); // Add items to list
var specificId = "123"; // specific id
var listObj1 = o1.Where(o => o.obj2List.Any(o2 => o2.sID == specificId) ||
                             o.obj3List.Any(o3 => o3.sID == specificId)).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 but you need `o.obj3List` and some code width formatting :)

Comment: Thanks --> works like a charm, I guess I was just over thinking it